# No sound in ubuntu 13.04 after logging in

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio

Good day!
I'm having a problem with no sound(at all) in Ubuntu 13.04 after log in (because when I'm logging in there is sound from OS) . 
I've checked the pulseaudio for automute and do the os recognizing my audio card in system settings(no problems have been detected). 
My speakers and headphones are ok. All these things have happened to me after latest software update.

Comment: Hope thats link below help you! <br>
http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/ <br>
Its worked for me. -:) (y)

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer but this didn't help me :(